# L'équivalent français de l'expression allemande « sich beim Essen anstellen »

Tags: expressions, allemand

> Und **beim Essen** **stellst** du **dich an** wie ein ausgehungerter Tiger.

Je cherche une expression française courante décrivant la façon un peu dégoûtante dont les enfants se ruent sur la nourriture à pleines mains et dents, en se salissant les mains, et avec la nourriture éparpillée dans tous les sens. Construction réfléchie ou pas, cette phrase marche bien ?

> Et quand tu manges tu **en mets** toujours **partout** comme un tigre affamé ! (C’est dégoûtant.)
>
> Et quand tu manges tu **t'en mets** toujours **partout** comme un tigre affamé !

Idem pour ceux qui essaient de manger proprement des ailes de poulet. C'est pas évident de les grignoter avec seulement des baguettes, et ce d'autant plus pour les enfants. Peut-on dire « en mettre partout » ou « s’en mettre partout » pour décrire des traces de sauce sur le visage et sur les mains ou un gros *bazar* sur la table ?

Answer (score 1):

*"En mettre partout"* (en mettre sur soi et autour de soi) et *"s'en mettre partout"* (en mettre sur soi) ont à peu près le même sens.

En Français, on dit surtout *"manger comme un cochon/goret/porc"* (porc étant le plus vulgaire) et pas *"comme un tigre"*.

Le choix entre les deux expressions dépend surtout du point de vue du locuteur (celui/celle qui prononce la phrase). Si le locuteur s'intéresse surtout aux vêtements, il/elle aura tendance à utiliser *"s'en mettre partout"* pour insister sur le fait qu'il va falloir laver ces vêtements. Si le locuteur s'intéresse plus à la nappe ou aux manières en général, l'expression *"en mettre partout"* est plus générale ; on peut même dire *"tu en as mis partout sur toi et sur la nappe"* pour mélanger les deux sens.